How to add Wifi functionality to core-image-x11 Yocto Image
I am building a Yocto image using the core-image-x11 recipe for a variscite dart-mx8m-mini board. The issue I am encountering is that when I boot into the image I dont have wifi capabilities.
ifconfig only provides etho0 and lo but no wlan0
ip link show
provides
lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:dc:7a:73:91:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: can0: <NOARP40000> mtu 16 qdisc noop qlen 10
    link/[280]

and nmcli device wifi list yields nothing
When I create a fsl-image-gui I have wlan0 and can connect the board to wifi.
So far I have tried the following.

Following variscites docs here. To turn on the wifi radio.
Made these additions to my local.conf
MACHINE_FEATURES:append = " wifi"
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " wifi"
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += " brcmfmac"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " \
    linux-firmware-bcm43430 \
    linux-firmware-bcm43455 \
    linux-firmware-nxp89xx \
    iw \
    wpa-supplicant \
    networkmanager \
    networkmanager-nmcli \ 
    firmware-nxp-wifi"


running modprobe brcmfmac to load the driver manually

here is my local.conf:
MACHINE ??= 'imx8mm-var-dart'
DISTRO ?= 'fsl-imx-xwayland'
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "dev-pkgs tools-sdk ssh-server-openssh"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    HALT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "2"

DL_DIR = "/home/ubuntu/yocto_downloads"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"

PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"

# Limit system resources used during build
BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "16"
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 16"

# Use preferred version for packages
PREFERRED_VERSION_nodejs = "20.13.0"

# Install additional packages
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " git \
 git-perltools \
 nodejs \
 nodejs-npm \
 openocd \
 libmhash \
 readline \
 cronie \
 feh \
 i2c-tools \
 dosfstools \
 tar \
 nginx \
 firmware-releases \
 libusb1 \
 libusb1-dev \
 dfu-util \
 unzip \
 vim \
 screen \
 openssl-bin \
 tzdata \
 bluez5 \
 nrfutil \
"

# Increase rootfs disk space
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "5242880"

# Add missing python packages
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " python3 python3-pip python3-configargparse"

# Enable X11
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " x11 \
 opengl \ 
"

Excluding all the things mentioned above
This my first project working on and learning embedded development so not sure what I am missing. Would really appreciate any insight.
Thank you.

SO is strictly for programming related questions. You're looking for [unix.se] instead.

You need to break down your effort into two parts: (a) Linux kernel configuration, and (b) userspace utilities. Search the web for tutorials. Learn to read the boot log for salient messages (instead of relying on the final state/results by shell commands). Pay attention to "firmware load" messages related to the WiFi adapter (i.e. what is enabled to service firmware load requests by a driver? Busybox?)
